# NextJs Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string When using Heroicons

Tags: reactjs, icons, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build an application that uses Tailwind CSS and Heroicons. However, when I use a few specific icons the application breaks (VeiwGridIcon, ChatIcon, BellIcon, CHeneronDownIcon). I already used other icons that worked fine but for some reason only they worked. I already tried reinstalling Tailwind and Hericons, but I got the same result. I also double-checked my imports, but they were all correct.

## Output/Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

## Code:

### index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Facebook</title>
      </Head>

      {/* Header */}
      <Header />

      <main>
        {/* Sidebar */}
        {/* Feed */}
        {/* Widgets */}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Header.js (code where the problem occurs):

```
import Image from "next/image";
import {
  BellIcon,
  ChatIcon,
  CheveronDownIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  UserGroupIcon,
  ViewGridIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import {
  FlagIcon,
  PlayIcon,
  SearchIcon,
  ShoppingCartIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import HeaderIcon from "./HeaderIcon";

function Header() {
  return (
    <div
      className="sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white flex 
    items-center p-2 lg:px-5 shadow-md"
    >
      {/* Left */}
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <Image
          src="https://links.papareact.com/5me"
          width={40}
          height={40}
          layout="fixed"
        />
        <div className="flex ml-2 items-center rounded-full bg-gray-100 p-2">
          <SearchIcon className="h-6 text-gray-600" />
          <input
            className="hidden md:inline-flex ml-2 items-center bg-transparent outline-none placeholder-gray-500 flex-shrink"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Facebook"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Center */}
      <div className="flex justify-center flex-grow">
        <div className="flex space-x-6 md:space-x-2">

          <HeaderIcon active Icon={HomeIcon} />
          <HeaderIcon Icon={FlagIcon} />
          <HeaderIcon Icon={PlayIcon} />
          <HeaderIcon Icon={ShoppingCartIcon} />
          <HeaderIcon Icon={UserGroupIcon} />
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Right */}
      <div className="flex items-center sm:space-x-2 justify-end">
        {/* Profile Pic */}
        <p className="whitespace-nowrap font-semibold pr-3">
          Anish Kunapareddy
        </p>
        // This code seems to be wrong
        <ViewGridIcon />
        <ChatIcon />
        <BellIcon />
        <CheveronDownIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

### HeaderIcon.js

```
function HeaderIcon({ Icon, active }) {
  return (
    <div
      className="flex items-center cursor-pointer
    md:px-10 sm:h-14 md:hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl
    active:border-b-2 active:border-blue-500 group"
    >
      <Icon
        className={`h-5 text-gray-500 text-center sm:h-7 mx-auto 
      group-hover:text-blue-500 ${active && "text-blue-500"}`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderIcon;
```

### globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .icon {
    @apply hidden xl:inline-flex p-2 h-10 w-10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the imported icons do not exists.
Your imports from "@heroicons/react" are wrong.

I see "CheveronDownIcon" does not exists in "@heroicons/react/solid"

Please check your code.

Answer (score 0):

HeroIcons name changes so often so please cross check name from heroicons website (https://heroicons.com/) before using it or else you'll get error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).